# Is there a way to get predicted topic probabilities in seededlda model in R?

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I am using R seededlda package to train a seeded lda model (https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda).

`model = textmodel_seededlda(dfmt, dict, residual = TRUE)`

`topics(model)` returns a list of predicted topic for each document. I was wondering if there is a way to get probabilities of all topics for each document?

I tried using posterior from topicmodels but it gave an error.

`probabilities <- topicmodels::posterior(seeded_lda)`

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘posterior’ for signature ‘"textmodel_lda", "missing"’

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue and have used a workaround based on the source code of `seededlda`. Namely, just fetching it directly from the output of `seededlda::textmodel_seededlda()`.

Below, you will find a replicable example of that workaround using the inbuilt corpus `quanteda::data_char_ukimmig2010` and a made up seed dictionary.

```
### packs
require(quanteda)
require(seededlda)
require(dplyr)

## prep the dfm
dfmat <- dfm(quanteda::data_char_ukimmig2010,
             remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbol = TRUE,
             remove = stopwords("en"))

## prep the seed dictionary (made up one)
my_dict <- dictionary(list(civil_rights = c("bisexual", "charter of rights", "civil libert", "disabilit", "discriminat", "diversity", "equal employm", "equal opportunit"),
                           healthcare = c( "health",  "hematolog","hepatolog","hiv", "obesity", "influenza"),
                           labour = c("hiring", "income", "salar", "union")))

## fit the model
slda <- textmodel_seededlda(x = dfmat, dictionary = my_dict, case_insensitive = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, residual = TRUE)

## extract the topic props across the documents
tidy_topics <- as_tibble(slda$theta, rownames = "doc_id") 

## it should end up looking like this
tidy_topics
# A tibble: 9 x 5
  doc_id       civil_rights healthcare labour  other
  <chr>               <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 BNP               0.561      0.204   0.0500 0.185 
2 Coalition         0.00382    0.0725  0.897  0.0267
3 Conservative      0.0102     0.00205 0.781  0.207 
4 Greens            0.00467    0.693   0.201  0.101 
5 Labour            0.0191     0.0924  0.840  0.0484
6 LibDem            0.018      0.23    0.538  0.214 
7 PC                0.0574     0.631   0.123  0.189 
8 SNP               0.00725    0.123   0.471  0.399 
9 UKIP              0.00980    0.0770  0.259  0.654
```

For reusability, I ended up writting these two functions for fetching word-topic probabilities and doc-topic probabilities. Both take as input the output of `seededlda::textmodel_seededlda()`.

```
### packs 
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

### get document topic probabilities
get_doc_topic_probs <- function(slda) {
  out <- slda$theta %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = "doc_id")
  return(out)
}

### get word topic probabilities
get_word_topic_probs <- function(slda) {
  out <- slda$phi %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = "topic") %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = !matches("topic"), names_to = "token", values_to = "prob")
  return(out)
}
```